# What kind of bulb is this? How to remove it?

Tags: light, replacement, bulb

I have a few burned out bulbs in my rental unit, which need to be replaced. Have never seen bulbs like this, cannot find any labels, and can’t even figure out how to remove it! Does anyone know what kind of bulb this is, or know how to find out?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the standard G9, and as said in answer should probably be just pulled out. They can be pretty tight, so handle with care. https://www.lampandlight.eu/what-type-of-fitting-do-i-need

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful

Comment: looks like a halogen lamp ... do not touch the new bulb with bare hands ... possibility of early failure if oils from your hands get on the glass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the kind I think it is, it pulls straight out; it's just held in place by friction. Use a towel or something so if it breaks you don't slice your hand, and wiggle it back and forth a bit along the long socket axis.

EDIT: These are called a Glass Wedge Bulb.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful